# Google In App Purchase Subscription Status from Purchase id

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am using flutter In_app_Purchase plugin to integrate in app purchase in flutter. I got success in buy subscription but How can I check the status of that subscription using purchase or transcationId
I have tried below
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Answer (score -1):

just call `_inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();`

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining why

Comment: if you call restorePurchases() then you can get all the purchase details from purchasestream. and then you can check your product id is available or not.